# what is the difference between openMP and thread pool?

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I want to know the basic difference between `*OpenMP*` and a *thread pool*? Also, if anyone could explain in relation to Linux, i.e using `*OpenMP*` for Linux.

Comment: The basic difference is that OpenMP run-times are often implemented over thread pools but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

OpenMP is a specification for a set of compiler directives, library routines, and environment variables that can be used to specify shared memory parallelism in Fortran and C/C++ programs.

Thread pool is a solution / pattern that using language / OS features or APIs to achieve parallelism. Thread pool is a concept that is not specific to a programming language.